Bitrix и его файл init.php
Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста проблема заключается в том что на локальном проекте под битрикс в папке php_interface создал файл init.php и просто хочу вывести текст - только вот выводит текст или что либо в самом конце сайта. Знаю то что все содержимое файла init должно подгружаться в начале сайта. Кто ни будь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваш текст, подготовленный вне шаблонов или компонент, выводился в начале сайта, необходимо сделать следующее.
В файле init.php установить некоторое свойство страницы:
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('sdkjdsfjh', 'Мой текст');

В шаблоне сайта после тега <body> вставить
<? $APPLICATION->ShowProperty('sdkjdsfjh'); ?>

А выводить что-либо непосредственно из init.php категорически не рекомендуется - можно поломать работу сайта.

Спасибо за ответ.

Не могли бы подсказать как мне определять собственные константы в битриксе? Спасибо

В файле init.php: define('NEWS_INFOBLOCK', 15);

Спасибо за ответ! Уже решил. Просто писал вместе BX_ROOT и вечно писало что константа не определена.
